# Spring Boot Security Configuration is not working

Tags: spring-boot, security, authentication, spring-security

I have two types of urls one are secured and one are not secured like registration and SignIn

I want "registration" and "SignIn" to byPass security and filters while all the other urls must pass through filters and security.

Following is my Security Configuration code but it is not working.

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AppSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    TempTokenGenerator tempTokenGenerator;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("notsecured/signin");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/", "**secured/**").authenticated()

            .and().logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .apply(new TempConfigurer(tempTokenGenerator));
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
```

what am I missing? What should I do to include "secured" urls in authentication and filters while excluding "unsecured" from authentication and filter.

```
 web.ignoring().antMatchers("notsecured/signin");
```

seems not working if I put

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

with

```
 http.authorizeRequests() to make secured urls work.
```

and if I put

```
.antMatchers("/","**/secured/**").authenticated()
```

with

```
.anyRequest().permitAll()
```

it is also not working.

Comment: http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/unsecured").permitAll() Are you expecting this?

Comment: @Sankar yes I want this for /unsecured but at the same time i want http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secured").authenticated.and()
           .apply(new TempConfigurer(tempTokenGenerator)); for /secured

Comment: http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/unsecured").permitAll() .antMatchers("/secured/**").hasRole("USER_ROLE") You can use like this.

Answer (score 0):

use `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method to secure your request-endpoints

```
  http.csrf().disable()
        .cors().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/notsecured/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/secured/**").fullyAuthenticated()
        .and().sessionManagement...
        .and().formLogin()
         ...
```

use `configure(WebSecurity web)` method to ignore static resources like images, css,...

Comment: I am already using configure(HttpSecurity http)and I want following filter to be applied only on secured urls      .and()
           .apply(new TempConfigurer(tempTokenGenerator));

Comment: Also the solution provided is not working, all urls are working fine without authentication.

Comment: the point is you should add multiple matchers that allow public access and secured access ```.antMatchers("matching public access").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("matching secured access").fullyAuthenticated()``` and yes, you can use ```.and() .apply(new TempConfigurer(tempTokenGenerator));```

Comment: thank you for the response but I had already applied matchers, you may see my OP. Following is how I am implementing matchers 

 .antMatchers("/secure/path/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/unsecured/path/**").fullyAuthenticated()
               .and().logout().permitAll()

but it is not working.